# setenv.bat is missing Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem during building a driver.
I downloaded visual studio 2013.
I downloaded WDK 8.1.
When I'm debugging the program it shows me an error:

```
"Error  1   error MSB3073: The command "call C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\\bin\setenv.cmd C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\ chk wxp
cd /d C:\FsFilter\FSFilter\
build.exe -I" exited with code 9009.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets   38  5   FsFilter"
```

Can you help me?

Here's a link to a snapshot of my project:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ex4p6x&s=8

Comment: Try putting the folder/filename in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

For others with the same question: the latest WDKs don't have setenv, so build old samples that use setenv and build.exe with old WDKs, e.g. [WDK 7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=11800).

[WDK 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)+ samples build in Visual Studio or on the command line with [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554644(v=vs.85).aspx).